# How to implement this control layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

I have several items I want to display. All the items have a title and subtitle. When I think about it's quite similar to bubbles in `WhatsApp` or `Facebook`. I guess these are implemented as 9-patch-drawables.

My background is like a circle and rectangle combined with two `TextView`s in front.

[image: sample]

My approaches:

- 9-patch-drawables: I can achieve the design, but I have to support several background colors. And images are very inflexible.
- drawable `xml`: when I create a drawable I can define an oval or a rectangle with corners as shapes. But the shapes scale. So in fact the circle part on the left is not really round.

Now I had a look at the `AnalogClock` which really is perfectly round, but it inherits from `View` and does measuring and painting by code.

So I assume I have to create a control on my own. Or are there any other approaches?

Requirements are:

- it must not skew, when I change any of the sides, but should scale
- I must be able to change the background color in code
- and of course I should be able to set the texts

Any hints for me how to achieve this?

Comment: See this if it can help you. https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. This library is for shaping images. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Put this Relativelayout in your .xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_button.xml** - add it in res > Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:shape="rectangle" > 
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
android:topRightRadius="0dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
/>
<solid
android:color="#4F4F4F"
/>
<size
android:width="220dp"
android:height="90dp"
/>
</shape>
```